# Buttons not scrolling Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been working in an animation for a webpage where I selected a circle and this circle become a carousel for showing more information and I integrate the idea of a youtuber (CodingNepal) of his infinite carousel, everything seems fine but the buttons (i tag) doesn't work, in his original work it does and I can't figure out why it doesn't work on mine. Some help?

HTML:

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="container-services">
      <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-canva">
          <div class="rotating-circle"></div>
          <div class="icons" >
            <div class="imgBx" style="--i:1;" id="imgService1">
              <button><img src="images/nails-service2.jpg"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="imgBx" style="--i:2;" id="imgService2">
              <button><img src="images/nails-service2.jpg"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="imgBx" style="--i:3;" id="imgService3">
              <button><img src="images/nails-service2.jpg"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="caro_canva">
            <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
            <ul class="caro">
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/nails-service2.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>Blanche Pearson</h2>
                <span>Sales Manager</span>
              </li>
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>Joenas Brauers</h2>
                <span>Web Developer</span>
              </li>
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>Lariach French</h2>
                <span>Online Teacher</span>
              </li>
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>James Khosravi</h2>
                <span>Freelancer</span>
              </li>
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/img-5.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>Kristina Zasiadko</h2>
                <span>Bank Manager</span>
              </li>
              <li class="card">
                <div class="img"><img src="images/img-6.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false"></div>
                <h2>Donald Horton</h2>
                <span>App Designer</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
/* services */

.service-container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
background: transparent;
}

.service-canva{
position: relative;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
opacity: 90%;
}

.rotating-circle{
position:absolute;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border: 8px solid #c7a265;
border-style: dotted;
border-radius: 50%;
opacity: 70%;
animation: rotation 30s linear infinite;
}

.imgBx{
position: relative;
width: 230px;
height: 230px;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: 0.5s;
overflow: hidden;
}

.imgBx img{
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
object-fit: cover;
z-index: 999;
filter: contrast(50%)
}

#imgService1{
transform: translate(60%, -45%);
}

#imgService2{
transform: translate(155%);
}

#imgService3{
transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
.service-canva .icons .imgBx:hover{
scale: 1.2;
}
.service-canva .icons .imgBx.active{
transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.service-canva .icons .imgBx.active img,
.service-canva .icons .imgBx:hover img {
transition: 0.5s ease-in;
filter: contrast(100%);
} 


.caro_canva {
max-width: 1100px;
height: 450px;
width: 450px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 5%;
left: 5%;
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}
.caro_canva.active{
transition: 3s ease-in;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
/* animation: showup1 2s ease-in; */
}
.caro_canva i {
top: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1.25rem;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
transform: translateY(-50%);
transition: transform 0.1s linear;
z-index: 1;
}
.caro_canva i:active{
transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.85);
}
.caro_canva i:first-child{
left: -22px;
}
.caro_canva i:last-child{
right: -22px;
}
.caro_canva .caro{
display: grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-auto-columns: calc((100% / 1) + 14px);
overflow-x: auto;
scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
gap: 26px;
border-radius: 8px;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
scrollbar-width: none;
}
.caro::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
.caro.no-transition {
scroll-behavior: auto;
}
.caro.dragging {
scroll-snap-type: none;
scroll-behavior: auto;
}
.caro.dragging .card {
cursor: grab;
user-select: none;
}
.caro :where(.card, .img) {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.caro .card {
scroll-snap-align: start;
list-style: none;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom: 15px;
flex-direction: column;
height: 450px;
width: 450px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.caro .card .img {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.card .img img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
object-fit: cover;
border: 4px solid #fff;
opacity: 0;
}
.caro .card h2 {
color: black;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 1.56rem;
margin: 30px 0 5px;
}
.caro .card span {
color: black;
font-size: 1.31rem;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const imgBxs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgBx');
const caro_canva = document.querySelector(".caro_canva");
const caro = document.querySelector(".caro"); 
const firstCardWidth = caro.querySelector(".card").offsetWidth;
const arrowBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".caro_canva i");
const caroChildrens = [...caro.children];

imgBxs.forEach(imgBx => {
    imgBx.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (imgBx.classList.contains('active')) {
            imgBx.classList.remove('active');
            caro_canva.classList.remove('active');
            imgBx.style.transform = '';
            imgBxs.forEach(img => {
                img.style.opacity = '1'; 
                imgBx.style.width = '';
                imgBx.style.height = '';
            });
        } else { 
            imgBxs.forEach(img => {
                img.classList.remove('active');
                caro_canva.classList.remove('active');
                img.style.opacity = '0';
                imgBx.style.width = '';
                imgBx.style.height = '';
            });
            imgBx.classList.add('active');
            caro_canva.classList.add('active');
            imgBx.style.opacity = '0';
            // imgBx.style.width = '450px';
            // imgBx.style.height = '450px';
        }
    });
});


window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    caro_canva.classList.remove('active');
    let activeExists = false;
    imgBxs.forEach(imgBx => {
        if (imgBx.classList.contains('active')) {
        activeExists = true;
        imgBx.style.opacity = '1';
        } else {
        imgBx.style.opacity = '0';
        imgBx.style.transform = '';
        }
    });
    if (!activeExists && imgBxs.length > 0) {
        imgBxs.forEach(imgBx => {
        imgBx.style.opacity = '1';
        });
    }
});

let isDragging = false, isAutoPlay = true, startX, startScrollLeft, timeoutId;

// Get the number of cards that can fit in the caro at once
let cardPerView = Math.round(caro.offsetWidth / firstCardWidth);

// Insert copies of the last few cards to beginning of caro for infinite scrolling
caroChildrens.slice(-cardPerView).reverse().forEach(card => {
    caro.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", card.outerHTML);
});

// Insert copies of the first few cards to end of caro for infinite scrolling
caroChildrens.slice(0, cardPerView).forEach(card => {
    caro.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", card.outerHTML);
});

// Scroll the caro at appropriate postition to hide first few duplicate cards on Firefox
caro.classList.add("no-transition");
caro.scrollLeft = caro.offsetWidth;
caro.classList.remove("no-transition");

// Add event listeners for the arrow buttons to scroll the caro left and right
arrowBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        caro.scrollLeft += btn.id === "left" ? -firstCardWidth : firstCardWidth;
    });
});

const dragStart = (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    caro.classList.add("dragging");
    // Records the initial cursor and scroll position of the caro
    startX = e.pageX;
    startScrollLeft = caro.scrollLeft;
}

const dragging = (e) => {
    if(!isDragging) return; // if isDragging is false return from here
    // Updates the scroll position of the caro based on the cursor movement
    caro.scrollLeft = startScrollLeft - (e.pageX - startX);
}

const dragStop = () => {
    isDragging = false;
    caro.classList.remove("dragging");
}

const infiniteScroll = () => {
    // If the caro is at the beginning, scroll to the end
    if(caro.scrollLeft === 0) {
        caro.classList.add("no-transition");
        caro.scrollLeft = caro.scrollWidth - (2 * caro.offsetWidth);
        caro.classList.remove("no-transition");
    }
    // If the caro is at the end, scroll to the beginning
    else if(Math.ceil(caro.scrollLeft) === caro.scrollWidth - caro.offsetWidth) {
        caro.classList.add("no-transition");
        caro.scrollLeft = caro.offsetWidth;
        caro.classList.remove("no-transition");
    }

    // Clear existing timeout & start autoplay if mouse is not hovering over caro
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    if(!caro_canva.matches(":hover")) autoPlay();
}

const autoPlay = () => {
    if(window.innerWidth < 800 || !isAutoPlay) return; // Return if window is smaller than 800 or isAutoPlay is false
    // Autoplay the caro after every 2500 ms
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => caro.scrollLeft += firstCardWidth, 2500);
}
autoPlay();

caro.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
caro.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
caro.addEventListener("scroll", infiniteScroll);
caro_canva.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => clearTimeout(timeoutId));
caro_canva.addEventListener("mouseleave", autoPlay);
```

I also use bootstrap for some styles.
Live in: https://codepen.io/Patricio-GarciaRs/pen/eYQMeEX

I can't make the buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, it was the `display:none` in the class `.caro_canva`, still don't know why or how this interaction work but if I discover it I will share it here, I also update the code in CodePen if anyone want to see it.

Hope this help someone!